# Euler's formula $e^{i\pi} = -1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I need some help to verify this, basically I need to use the rule:

$$\exp(-x) = \frac{1}{\exp(x)}$$

to verify that

$$e^{i\pi} = -1$$

Except I'm not sure how to do it, I mean I know of the trigonometric identity of $$e^{i\pi} = \cos(\pi) + i\sin(\pi)$$, how do we get $-1$?

Comment: When did $\cos\pi$ become $1$?

Comment: I edited, I was thinking of cos^2(x) + isin^2(x) = 1, sorry about that...

Comment: @Myzanthros Well, that isn't correct. It is
$$\cos^2(x) + \sin^2(x) = 1 $$
without any $i$. I think you're mixing up your identities.

Comment: That last one is also wrong, there is no $i$ in it. Edit: @Eff, you got seconds ahead of me :)

Comment: Hmmm, I will re-read that chapter again, it has been quite some time since I handled euler stuff but thanks for pointing that out too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that

- $\cos(\pi)=-1$
- $\sin(\pi)=0$

Then:

$$e^{i\pi} = \cos(\pi) + i\sin(\pi)=-1+i\cdot 0$$